# Запись в базу данных Oracle кириллицы через Post запрос на C++

Tags: oracle, c++

Кодировка базы данных utf8. Кодировка сайта тоже utf8. Но в итоге туда записываются вопросительные знаки/ромбики. Используется, собственно, OCI.

Comment: Исходники можно глянуть?

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте настройки клиентской части `Oracle`. Если дело проиисходит в `Windows` то надо проверить ключ реестра, если в *NIX системах - переменную окружения `NLS_LANG`.
Чтобы не мучиться с руссифицированными сообщениями об ошибках рекомендую присвоить переменной значение `AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`.
Переменная окружения работает и в Windows, причём имеет приоритет перед настройками в реестре. Достаточно в командной строке выполнить команду

```
set NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```

и затем запустить приложение в том же окне из командной строки (ну или сделать сооветствующий командный файл).

Подробнее про настройки можно почитать [здесь](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html) или [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14312/gblsupp.htm#BCEEHABC).

Если не устраивает зависимость от настройки среды на компьютере с которого осуществляется соединение то можно указать желаемую кодировку при инициализации соединения при помощи `OCIAttrSet()` ([документация](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch6.htm#1005295)).