# 1) Проблема с кириллицей (выводятся знаки вопроса) 2) Не могу поменять CHARACTER SET

Tags: oracle

Открываю PL/SQL Developer БД запросом и в текстовых полях отображаются кракозябры? Как победить? Подугли и нашел что кодировка должна быть `RUSSIAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251`. Установил её в переменных среды клиента.

Но теперь при в ходе в PL/Sql Developer пишет следующие:

> Database charter set (AL32UTF8) and Client character set (CL8MSWIN1251) are different.

Еще подуглил и понял что видимо нужно поменять `CHARACTER` в параметрах. Но я не админ и честно говоря не знаю как это делать. 
Еще погуглил попробовал от пользователя system запустить:

```
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
```

и

```
ALTER DATABASE NATIONAL CHARACTER SET INTERNAL_USE CL8MSWIN1251;
ORA-12718: operation requires connection as SYS
```

Попытался дать права на:

```
grant update on sys.nls_database_parameters to system;
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Подскажите пжл:

1. Правильным ли я иду путем?
2. Как изменить на стройки и что для этого надо если можно пошагово?
3. а. SQLplus у меня тоже не настроен если он нужен.
   б. Если нужен sysdba его пароль я тоже не знаю видимо он стандартный должен быть?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запись в базу данных Oracle кириллицы через Post запрос на C++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/374578/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-oracle-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-post-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)